# Product description read more in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i need to have read more button in product description after 50 words in my Woocommerce store. It is possible with some code? Thanks

Comment: in which page ? listing pages ?

Comment: yes sorry, in product page. the main description not the sort one.

Comment: can you please show us the screenshots ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ht9io7 here is.

Comment: this seems product details page

Comment: Ok, i need readmore button in red border place. Its this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162082/discussion-between-alice-and-vachos).

Answer (score 0):

open yourwoocommerce/content-single-product.php file and import global variable $more, then set it to false to get the part before the tag:

```
<div class="collapsed-content">
        <?php
            global $more;
            $temp = $more;
            $more = false;
            $short_description = get_the_content( '' );
            echo $short_description;
            $more = $temp;
        ?>
</div>
```

The full description text can be displayed by calling the_content() function. Create a new `<div>` below your short description and echo your full description there:

```
<div class="full-content">
    <?php
        $full_description = the_content();
    ?>
</div>
```

The next thing you want to do is to change CSS of this `<div>`, so it wouldn’t be displayed before we need it:

```
.full-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Next, set your jQuery function to toggle these `<div>`s, upon clicking on “Read more..” link.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#readMore, #readLess").click(function(){
            $(".collapsed-content").toggle('slow', 'swing');
            $(".full-content").toggle('slow', 'swing');
            $("#readMore").toggle();// "read more link id"
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

So, by default only a short description before the < – – MORE – – > tag is shown. When user clicks on the link it just replaces it with the full description. Add some animations if you want. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you need a tab called 'More' to show product description.

Check out the following code which will add a new tab (link) called more and will show you product details under that.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'add_my_tab');

function add_my_tab($tabs){
    $tabs['details_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => 'More',
        'priority'  => 1,
        'callback'  => 'tab_content',
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function tab_content(){
    global $product;
    echo $product->get_description();
}
```

Paste the code into your theme's functions.php

I have found this code in this [link](http://www.mingocommerce.com/add-new-tab-to-product-details-page/). You can check there for more details. I have just modified that code according to your description.